# Select between skip-gram and CBOW model for training word2Vec in gensim

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

Is it possible to choose between the `Skip-gram` and the `CBOW` model in *Gensim* when training a *Word2Vec* model?

Answer (score 20):

Yes. The initialization parameter `sg` controls the mode. If True-ish (`sg=1`), skip-gram is used; if False-ish (`sg=0`), CBOW is used.

The [docs for gensim's Word2Vec class](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec) cover this.